# On a bound about $\sum_{n\leq n}\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}} M \left(\frac{x}{n} \right) \right] $

Tags: summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

From the fact that $f(x)= \left[f( x) \right]+ \left\{ f(x) \right\}  $, where $ \left\{ x \right\} $ is the **fractional part function**, one can write by a direct substitution for the function $M(x)=\sum_ {n\leq x}\mu(n)$, where $\mu(n)$ is the **Möbius function** that 
$$M(x)=\sqrt{x} \left[ \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \right]+\sqrt{x} \left\{  \frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \right\} . $$
On the other hand we know the following

> **Proposition.** For $x>1$, $$\sum_{n\leq x}M \left( \frac{x}{n} \right) =1.$$

Then I can compute 
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}} M \left(\frac{x}{n} \right)  \right] =O \left( \sqrt{x} \right), $$
with the obvious bound for the fractional part function, and since 
$O \left( \sqrt{x}\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=O(\sqrt{x}) $.

But I don't know if such an asymptotic has a mathematical sense. Is it possible to improve it much more? I didn't draw a plot of this function.

> **Question.** Is it possible  for $x>1$ to compute or to improve: 
>   $$\sum_{n\leq x}\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}} M \left(\frac{x}{n} \right)  \right] =O \left( \sqrt{x} \right)\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $$\sqrt{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ll\sqrt{x}
 $$ since $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sum_{n\leq x}1=\sqrt{x}
  $$ and from Abel's summation we have $$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\left[t\right]}{t^{3/2}}dt\ll\sqrt{x}
 $$ so your trivial bound is $$ \begin{align}\sum_{n\leq x}\sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right]=
  & \sqrt{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right\} \right)
  \\ =
  & 1-\sqrt{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left\{ \sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right\} 
  \\ \ll
 & x.
  \end{align} $$ I think it is not simple to do better. Note that even if we assume the Riemann hypothesis we have, for all $\epsilon>0$
 , $$\sqrt{\frac{n}{x}}M\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\ll\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\epsilon}
 $$ and also holds $$\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}}<-1.009,\,\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{M\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{x}}>1.06.
 $$

Comment: Truly I had a great mistake when I've computed $O(\sqrt{x})$, now I am saying very thanks much to do the right computations, is then your propositon. Very thanks much M. Cantarini.